# Angular rxjs Observable.timer is not a function with import

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, ngrx

In my angular application I recieve the following error:

> ERROR TypeError:
>   rxjs_Observable__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_4__.Observable.timer is not a
>   function
>       at SwitchMapSubscriber.project (hybrid.effect.ts:20)
>       at SwitchMapSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/operators/switchMap.js.SwitchMapSubscriber._next
>   (switchMap.js:34)
>       at SwitchMapSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.Subscriber.next
>   (Subscriber.js:54)
>       at FilterSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/operators/filter.js.FilterSubscriber._next
>   (filter.js:38)
>       at FilterSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.Subscriber.next
>   (Subscriber.js:54)
>       at ScannedActionsSubject.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subject.js.Subject.next
>   (Subject.js:47)
>       at SafeSubscriber._next (store.js:332)
>       at SafeSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub (Subscriber.js:195)
>       at SafeSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.SafeSubscriber.next
>   (Subscriber.js:133)
>       at Subscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.Subscriber._next
>   (Subscriber.js:77)

My code looks like the following:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Effect, Actions } from '@ngrx/effects';
import { of } from 'rxjs/observable/of';
import { map, catchError, switchMap } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/timer';

import * as hybridActions from '../actions/hybrid.action';
import { FleetStatusReportService } from '../../fleet-status-report.service';

@Injectable()
export class HybridEffects {
  constructor(
    private actions$: Actions,
    private fleetstatusreportService: FleetStatusReportService
  ) {}

  @Effect()
  loadHybrid$ = this.actions$.ofType(hybridActions.LOAD_HYBRID).pipe(
    switchMap(() => Observable.timer(0, 900000)),
    switchMap(() => {
      return this.fleetstatusreportService.getHybridPerformance().pipe(
        map(hybrid => new hybridActions.LoadHybridSuccess(hybrid)),
        catchError(error => of(new hybridActions.LoadHybridFail(error)))
      );
    })
  );
}
```

I've been looking around on the web and to me it looks like that the latest angular version would use

```
import 'rxjs/add/observable/timer';
```

however, it doesn't seem to work. Does anyone know how to solve this problem?

Comment: Which version of rxjs are you using?

Comment: Im using rxjs 6!

Comment: The answer below should help then

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If you use latest angular with RxJS 6, then you need to do it like this:

```
import { map, catchError, switchMap } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { Observable, of, timer } from 'rxjs';

loadHybrid$ = this.actions$.ofType(hybridActions.LOAD_HYBRID).pipe(
  switchMap(() => timer(0, 900000)),
  switchMap(() => {
    return this.fleetstatusreportService.getHybridPerformance().pipe(
      map(hybrid => new hybridActions.LoadHybridSuccess(hybrid)),
      catchError(error => of(new hybridActions.LoadHybridFail(error)))
    );
  })
);
```

Basically there is no monkey patching of `Observable` anymore, now you need to import that `timer` function from `rxjs` and use that instead.

More about this change is here:

https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/doc/pipeable-operators.md

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I got it to work. However, when I wrote import { Observable, of, timer } from 'rxjs'; , it gave me the following message when I hovered over timer: "'timer' is declared but its value is never read.", and an error in my code (since it didn't pick it up I assume). If I added import 'rxjs/add/observable/timer'; it solved the problem. You know why this is the case?

Comment: Sounds like its just bad guess of your IDE. If you do not get any compile errors, then your code is valid. Importing it from `rxjs` directly should be preferred way as of v6.