# spyOn Observable timer not possible - Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type 'never'

Tags: timer, rxjs, jasmine, rxjs-observables

I get the error

```
Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type 'never'.
```

When trying to spy on `timer` like this:

```js
it('should start a timer', async () => {
  spyOn(Observable, 'timer');
});
```

Import statement:

```js
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
```

Any idea why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is TypeScript telling you there's a problem with the thing you're trying to spy on.

From [`@types/jasmine`](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/jasmine/v2/index.d.ts#L126):

`declare function spyOn<T>(object: T, method: keyof T): jasmine.Spy;`

In checking your code, TypeScript attempts to resolve the second argument's type: `keyof Observable`. This is resolving to `never`, seemingly because `Observable` (as you're importing it) has no keys that are extractable by `keyof`.

Comment: I saw others executing `spyOn(Observable, 'timer');`, but why can't I execute it?

Comment: The other examples were probably using an older version of RxJS. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52343011/angular-rxjs-observable-timer-is-not-a-function-with-import).

Comment: Okay. I wonder how I could then test if `subscribe()` was executed on a timer, but that's  not what I asked for in my question.